SpringSecurity+Oauth2 : how to get username from Apple Login
I'm implementing Google, Apple, and other OAuth logins using Spring Security. When it comes to Apple login, I want to save the userName to the database. However, since the redirect URL is automatically handled by Spring Security, it's difficult to debug and confirm this on the server.
I have configured the scope correctly, so I can see the username in JSON format from the Google Admin Console's network tab. But, how can I capture this on the server?
Here is the configuration in my SecurityConfig.
.oauth2Login(oauth2 -> oauth2
                        .loginPage("/v2/oauth2/loginPage") // OAuth 로그인 페이지 URL
                        .authorizationEndpoint(authorization -> authorization
                                .authorizationRequestResolver(customAuthorizationRequestResolver)
                        )
                        .tokenEndpoint(tokenEndpointConfig -> tokenEndpointConfig
                                .accessTokenResponseClient(customTokenResponseClient)) // 커스텀 토큰 응답 클라이언트 설정
                        .redirectionEndpoint(redirectionEndpointConfig -> redirectionEndpointConfig
                                .baseUri("/v2/login/oauth2/code/*"))
                        .userInfoEndpoint(userInfoEndpoint -> userInfoEndpoint
                                .userService(customOAuth2UserService)
                        )
                        .successHandler(loginAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                        .failureHandler(loginAuthenticationFailureHandler)
                );

